# Bind models to each other, or get synchronised computed properties

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Sometimes the model abstraction is not enough, and you feel the need to keep two different models synchronised.

For example, i have two lists connected by an [angular sortable](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-sortable), which requires a model like the following:

```
left = [{name:"one"}, {name:"two"}];
right = [{name:"three"}];
```

But i want to allow the user to configure this also with a list of switches implemented like checkboxes (angular `input.checkbox` directive). This would require a model like:

```
elements = [{
    name:"one",
    position:"left"
}, {
    name:"two",
    position:"left"
}, {
    name:"three",
    position:"right"
}]
```

So in order to cleanly wire the views to some controllers, i need the controllers to reflect some kind of *data view* of the same higher level model. Or i need two models which can stay synchronised among them.

This is also referred around as having a *computed property* in the same model, but the proposed solution is usually to use a function, which would not provide a two way binding on the data returned by the function.

What is needed here would be functionally equivalent to what filters do, that is, keeping a transformed version of some data in sync with the original data.

How to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The solution i am going to use to fix my problem does not answer this question, but i put it here as a reference of a quick and dirty solution to the problem.

I compute a different version of my model with a function enclosed in `$scope.$watch`, and i add event handlers there in order to properly update the model.

A live demo here, forked from the ui-sortable demo http://codepen.io/danse/pen/xlptu

Here a nicer version from a colleague http://codepen.io/danse/pen/ovGkq

This works, but according to me it's ugly, and it breaks the whole idea of angular of having two way binded views